# How to modify global variable value within a function which is passed as a parameter to a wapper(like callback)?

Tags: bash, shell, function-pointers

I have a question about the function as parameter of bash.

If following logic is executed:

```
Var=5
Step=2

funct() {
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    Var=$(($Var+$Step))
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}

main()
{
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    funct
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}

main
```

output is

```
[Line = 13] 5
[Line = 6] 5
[Line = 8] 7
[Line = 15] 7
```

as you see, Var is changed as expected.

**However, please check the following example where function is passed as parameter to a wrapper.**

```
Var=5
Step=2

funct() {
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    Var=$(($Var+$Step))
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}

main()
{
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    funct
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}



main2()
{
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    ($1)
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}

main

main2 funct
```

the result is

```
[Line = 12] 5
[Line = 5] 5
[Line = 7] 7
[Line = 14] 7
[Line = 21] 7
[Line = 5] 7
[Line = 7] 9
[Line = 23] 7
```

Please notice that the callback wrapper CANNOT actually modify Var.

Since I am doing a framework now so may wish some common actions to be functions as parameters of a general control flow.

How can I make the wrapper which takes function as parameter to really modify global variable?

Thanks~

Answer (score 4):

```
($1)
```

Runs `$1` in a subshell, because that is [what parentheses do](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) in a shell. If you run a function in a subshell, it cannot change global variables (although its execution environment is initialised with the parent shell's variables, so it can see them).

If you want the callback function to run inside the current execution environment, don't put it in parentheses. Use

```
"$1"
```

The quotes avoid issues with `$1` containing whitespace or glob characters.

A more common idiom is

```
"$@"
```

which passes through additional command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
main2()
{
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
    $1
    echo "[Line = $LINENO] $Var"
}
```

I found remove the () works but do NOT know why...

Comment: What you don't explain is why you put them there in the first place.